# Attach user details to request object in nestjs

Tags: nestjs

I set globally middleware to attach data to request object and it work in http...

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
```

But it is not work in gateway(websocket)...

> why this middleware that set on all routes not work in gateway(websocket)...?

or

> what is the best way for attach authorized user to request in http and websocket...?

Comment: How you attach data to  the request in the AuthMiddleware

i am stucked with that

Answer (score 0):

You've got the answer from creator of the framework. Just in case someone is facing the same

> Middleware don't apply to the websockets - it's not an issue. Use interceptor/guard instead.

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1634#issuecomment-472553863